# PDO loop insert

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a database:

```
------------------------------
name    |extension  |filesize
------------------------------
abc     | php       | 12
def     | php       | 18
ghi     | bat       | 32
jkl     | bat       | 24
mno     | php       | 30
```

I want to specify all extensions and summarize filesizes, so it is working pretty well:

```
$sql= "SELECT extension, SUM(filesize) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY extension";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
 echo $row['extension'] . " - " . $row['1'] . "<br>";
}
```

The output is:

```
php - 60
bat - 56
```

But now I want to insert these results in a new table (using PDO of course). I want to have a new table:

```
---------------------
ext     |sumfilesize
---------------------
php     | 60
bat     | 56
```

I suppose I have to make some query in while loop but is it possible to make a query inside a query?
How can I do it?

Comment: It is possible but that would be a denormalization and you have to have a very strong reason to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO myTotalTable (extension,total) SELECT extension,SUM(filesize) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY extension";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not creating the new table inside your while loop you're good to go. Just put the query to insert the values in your database in your while loop and you are done.
Code should then look like this:

```
$sql= "SELECT extension, SUM(filesize) AS total FROM mytable GROUP BY extension";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
  echo $row['extension'] . " - " . $row['1'] . "<br>";
  $query = "INSERT INTO TableName (ext, sumfilesize) VALUES ($row['extension'], $row['1'])";
  $query->execute();
}
```